# .Net MAUI app transferred from pc to mac won't run on iOS Simulator: "Could not find any available provisioning profile"

Tags: ios, maui, code-signing, visual-studio-mac-2022

I created a .Net MAUI app on Visual Studio for Windows. Now I need to work on it on Visual Studio for Mac. I cannot build it due to the following error: Could not find any available provisioning profiles for MyProject on iOS.

I tried whatever I could, created a new project on xCode with the same bundle identifier as in my Info.plist etc. Nothing helps. All I want currently is just to be able to run the app locally. I don't need any signing for this. When I create a new blank Maui app on Mac, neither its project file nor Info.plist mentions anything about signing or bundle. And it runs without problem.
I tried to remove that stuff from my project, but keep getting this error. What makes the project require a provisioning profile, and how can I prevent it?

Comment: You said: "Now I need to work on it on Visual Studio for Mac." How do you run your project on the Mac, upload it to GitHub and then download it? You can build a blank project with a Mac, right?

Comment: @DongzhiWang-MSFT I just copied the project az .zip and emailed myself. Then downloaded on Mac. Yes, I can build a blank MAUI project on Mac.

Comment: You want to run on iOS Simulator?  Did you check that `Debug | iPhoneSimulator` is selected as target in VS?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I did

Comment: Make sure you copy ONLY source files. Or after copying, delete all `.obj` and `.bin` folders. Also delete hidden `.vs` folder. The usual way to move between computers is to upload *sources only* to a private github repo (or other online source-code-control), then download that repo on the new computer. This is much easier to maintain.

Comment: @DavidShochet You can try to upload to github, and then download the project through mac to see if this problem occurs.

Comment: Looks like the issue is resolved after removing aps-environment key from Entitlements.plist...

Comment: @DavidShochet You can post your answer as it will help others who have similar issue. If you don't mind, I can help you do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As David Shochet said, you need to delete the `aps-environment` key from `Entitlements.plist` to solve this problem.